# Stream builder returns null on released flutter app using firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder, flutter-streambuilder

`StreamBuilder` widget works well on debug mode but on release mode returns `null`. I had tried several solutions found here, but none worked. So maybe I am missing something in my code. Here are my source codes.

**store_screen.dart**

```
StreamBuilder<List<StoreItem>>(
  initialData: [],
  stream: widget.bloc.getStores(),
  builder: (context, querySnapshot) {
    if (querySnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
      List<StoreItem> stores = querySnapshot.data!;
      ....
    } else if (querySnapshot.hasError) {
      print(querySnapshot.toString());
      ....
    } else {
      ....
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
  },
),
```

**store_bloc.dart**

```
Stream<List<StoreItem>> getStores() {
  final snapshot = database.getDataFromCollection('owner');

  return snapshot.map((event) => event.docs
      .map((e) => StoreItem.fromMap(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
      .toList());
}
```

Comment: what package are you using for database?

Comment: I am using cloud_firestore from firebase.

Comment: I think you need to await for database, like this: final snapshot = await database.getDataFromCollection('owner');

Comment: Does stream builder support await? Because, I have tried seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If it works perfectly on debug mode, but failing only on release version, then it can be because of you didn’t add app hash code on firebase config. Also I suggest to check privacy rules of database and make it properly for production.

Comment: I have added the hash codes on firebase config and also for the firestore rules are well implemented.

Comment: Then run app on device in release mode with flutter run —release. And let me know what is the cause of error

Comment: I had run the app in release mode, it returns an error that the snapshot is null. This means that the snapshot has no data. But in debug mode the snapshot has data that's the problem am facing.